# Select nth page rather than page n

Tags: php, mysql

I have a webpage which paginates results from my MySQL database. The code below is used in creating a dropdown menu to navigate the results. At present it is set so that it selects page *n*; this assumes that when I request page 30 (for example) the relevant record is stored at line 30 of the result set, but from some testing this clearly isn't the case. How should I alter this so that it returns the *n* th page instead? I know it's the while statement that needs adjusting, but I just can't quite figure it out.

```
    //…previous code…

    $rowsPerPage = 1;

    // by default we show first page
    $pageNum = 1;

    // if $_GET['page'] defined, use it as page number
    if(isset($_GET['page']))
    {
        $pageNum = $_GET['page'];
    }

    $offset = ($pageNum - 1) * $rowsPerPage;

    $query3 = 'SELECT t1.s_name AS t1_sname, t1.uh_heading AS t1_unit, t1.ut_latin AS t1_latin, t1.ut_english AS t1_english, t1.uh_id, t1.chapter_sequence AS t1_chapters, t1.unit_sequence AS t1_units, 
                      t2.s_name AS t2_sname, t2.ut_latin AS t2_latin, t2.ut_english AS t2_english, t2.chapter_sequence AS t2_chapters, t2.unit_sequence AS t2_units
               FROM vw_source_text_and_translation AS t1
               LEFT JOIN vw_source_text_and_translation AS t2
               ON (t2.uh_id = t1.uh_id AND t2.s_id = " ' . $_SESSION['source2'] . ' " )
               WHERE t1.s_id =  " ' . $_SESSION['source1'] . ' "
               ORDER BY t1.chapter_sequence, t1.unit_sequence' .
               " LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage";

//...more code...

    $query4   = 'SELECT uh_id, chapter_sequence, unit_sequence, uh_heading 
             FROM vw_source_text_and_translation 
             WHERE s_id = "' . $_SESSION['source1'] . '"';

//...more code...

    $rows= $result4;
    $numrows = 0;
    $nav  = '';
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) 
    {
      $nav .= ' <option value="'. $row['uh_id'] .'"> '. 
              $row['chapter_sequence'] .'.'.$row['unit_sequence'] .
              ' - '. $row['uh_heading'] .'</option>';
      $numrows ++;
    }

    /*…more code… */
```

OK, so with some help this is partially fixed; the while statment now reads as:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) 
 {
  $numrows ++;
  $nav .= ' <option value=" ' . $numrows . '"> '. $row['chapter_sequence'] .'.'.
             $row['unit_sequence'] .' - '. $row['uh_heading'] .'</option>';
 }
```

This fixes the pagination, though I still have a problem that some records are not displayed, even though when I run $query3 in MySQL Toolkit with set values for $_SESSION['source1'] and $_SESSION['source2'] it works fine. It seems that if there is a NULL value for t2.ut_latin or t2.ut_english, then no data is displayed, even though it recognises that there is a record, which has been paginated. However, I guess that goes beyond the topic of this question, so I might have to repost this in a new question.

Comment: Do you have an `ORDER BY` clause in your query?

Comment: There's no different between *page n* and *nth page*, unless your pages start at 0...

Comment: please add your query if you need help.The code alone isn't very useful

Comment: Does your pagination work by allowing one pagination link per page of your website (like chapters in a book) or does page 2 (for example) bring back pages 10-20 (again for example) like how a blog works?

Comment: Hope the update makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a LIMIT clause with an offset.

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY something
LIMIT 40, 10
```

To calculate the offset multiply the page number (starting from 0) by the number of rows per page.